# Importing LiDAR data and additional info to database with pdal pipeline

Tags: lidar, pdal

I have a pipeline.json file that inserts laz files into the database. This creates a default column "pa" in the database and successfully inserted the associated value in each row. I need to include additional columns into the database for the source name and source date which I can retrieve via regex from the name of the laz files using a bash script and have the values replace the variable in the pipeline.json file. But I need to populate each row of the source name/source date respective to its "pa" value. What is the best approach to this? I tried to include a pre_sql and also tested with a post_sql but it doesn't seem to work. I also tried to create a python file to include the json pipeline but it's complaining that the connection key/value is too long. So, that's another issue I'm facing.
Here's a portion of what was attempted in the pipeline json file:

```
...
    {
      "type": "writers.pgpointcloud",
      "connection": "host='xxxxxxx' dbname='xxxxx' user='xxxxx' password='xxxxxx' port='xxxx'",
      "schema": "xx",
      "table": "lidar",
      "pre_sql": "INSERT INTO xx.lidar (source_name, source_date) VALUES ('SOURCENAME', 'SOURCEDATE')",
      "compression": "dimensional",
      "srid": "4326"
    }
```

Comment: I think it's impossible to do that with pdal. The only solution I can think, is to use, after the insertion, an SQL query that would identify the las file corresponding to each pg_point cloud patch from the las and patchs bbox.

Comment: Hey, thank you for confirming this. I'm not too familiar with PDAL and just wanted to make sure. I actually used this step to resolve this issue and it works great. After an insertion, I used SQL query to check if the cells in column pa has the inserted value, and if the pa column has values and the source_name/source_date are empty, to add in the source_name and source_date values I had stored via regex from the unzipped path.

Comment: This seems to me to be the best way to proceed at the moment. Let's hope that pdal will be improved to natively allow this kind of queries.